# enable remote debugging in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, glassfish

Guide me how can i enable the remote debugging in eclipse. i make an ear file and deploy it to  another machine which is connected through putty and proxifier and also the server is already running. Steps which i have taken to enable remote debugging:
1 :I enabled the debug option in glassfish running on other machine and got the port i.e. by default 9090 on which it will listen.
2: Next i have gone in Eclipse to enable the remote debugging where i entered the ip of the VM on which my glassfish is running and port on which debugger will listen.
3: then in windows>preferences>network Connection, i have added proxy setting in http using host and the port address(same mentioned as above in step 2).

---

Now once i enable the debug, i could see the eclipse in profixer is trying to connect with that ip, but after some time either i got an error "Failed to connect to remote VM Received invalid handshake" or "failed to connect to remote vm software caused connection abort recv failed" in eclipse. Please guide

Answer (score 0):

I think OS on which you have hosted application has firewall setting that are not allow you to connect to the glassfish server. If this is the case then add port that you are using for debug on your server's firewall port list.

Comment: can you access VM ip in your browser URL?